# Javascript - Use a dropdown menu to dynamically change a title's h tag

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm not really sure where to start coding with this one. I'm looking to use a dropdown menu with the h tag's in it, h1, h2, h3 etc... and then using javascript to dynamically change the titles h tag. so if it's by default a h1 then i use the dropdown menu and change it to a h3, it will then change the title's h tag from h1 to h3.

So i'm thinking maybe something like give the title an id, target it by that id, then each dropdown will have a number value, maybe use javascript substring and replace the number value in the h1 with the number value from the dropdown to dynamically change the title h tag.

So i'm not sure if im just making this way more complicated than it needs to be or not. Has anyone tried this before or got any pointers?

Let me know if im not being clear on what i'm trying to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically change some "title" element in a page by offering a select menu in which a user can choose different styles (H1, H2, ...)?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. `dynamically change the titles h tag` there is another `h` tag in body? apart from drop down?

Comment: If I understood you want to create a text-editor with JavaScript? Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the `change` event on a `select` element that creates a clone element with the same `innerHTML` as the previous one, just with a different tag name, and assign the `outerHTML` of the created element to the `outerHTML` of the original title element.

```js
s.addEventListener('change', function() {
  title.outerHTML = Object.assign(document.createElement(this.value), {id: 'title', innerHTML: title.innerHTML}).outerHTML;
})
```

```html
<select id="s">
  <option value="h1">h1</option>
  <option value="h2">h2</option>
  <option value="h3">h3</option>
  <option value="h4">h4</option>
  <option value="h5">h5</option>
  <option value="h6">h6</option>
</select>

<h1 id="title">Title</h1>
```

Comment: ye this actually seems to be along the lines of what i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @ddd No problem. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have in mind for this is simply to create your own H1, H2 classes according to these [Default CSS Settings](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp) (scroll down about a third of the page). Then you can dynamically change them as in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9yd8epso/

html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>This is my title:</div>
      <div class="default" id="myTitle">Hello World</div>      
      <div>Please choose style: <select onchange="doChange(this)">
        <option>default</option>
        <option>h1</option>
        <option>h2</option>
      </select></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
function doChange(e){
  document.getElementById("myTitle").className=e.value;
}
```